# Assign extern array to local variable without copying the array

Tags: c, arrays

I have an extern array, and I would like to be able to modify it by using local variable like:

**Header file**

```
typedef char VAR[200]
extern VAR B={0}
```

**Main file**

```
VAR S=B;
```

Is there any way that I can do that without copying the array?

Comment: If you'd copied the array, you'd not modify the (external) original!

Comment: You can't do array assignment in C; you have to use a subterfuge such as `memmove(S, B, sizeof(VAR))` (or `memcpy()`), or embed the array within a structure and use structure assignment.  Note that your code seems to be trying to initialize a local array from the external array, whereas you say you'd like to modify the external array from the local variable.  Ultimately, it doesn't matter; you can't assign one array to another regardless.  But your question is currently mildly confusing.

Comment: How about `static VAR *p = &B; ....  (*p)[42] = 'x';`?  Is this the kind of "like to be able to modify it by using local variable" you are looking for?

Comment: chux has a good idea about it. Use a local pointer to external array, and use it as an array.

Comment: `extern VAR B={0}` is a mistake. Besides the missing semicolon, having an initializer would make this a definition rather than a declaration , so including the header from multiple units causes undefined behaviour.  Please post real code

Comment: You could do `char *S = B;` and then use `S` like `B` in most ways

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to be able to modify it by using local variable
>
> Is there any way that I can do that without copying the array?

Create a pointer the to `extern` array.

```
#define VAR_N 200
typedef char VAR[VAR_N];
extern VAR B;

void foo(void) {
  VAR *p = &B;  // p is a pointer to B

  printf("%c\n", B[42]); // print original value of one element
  (*p)[42] = 'x';
  printf("%c\n", B[42]); // print changed value of one element

  // modify all elements of B
  for (size_t i=0; i<VAR_N; i++) {
    (*p)[i] = 'y';
  }
  printf("%c\n", B[42]); // print changed value of one element

  // modify all elements of B
  // Notice *p has the same size as B
  size_t n = sizeof *p / sizeof (*p)[0];
  memset(p, 'z', n);
  printf("%c\n", B[42]); // print changed value of one element
}
```

Comment: `[42]` => `[i]`